# AWS EC2 public access to service running on private IP

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running [deepracer for cloud](https://github.com/aws-deepracer-community/deepracer-for-cloud), on an EC2 instance.

This is creating a video stream on the instance's private IP on port 8001. But I cannot view it.

I get the html content when I curl the port from the instance, but I cannot just go to the instance's `public_IP:8001` or to the private IPs from my machine.

I had a look at similar posts on here, most of which suggest using a port forwarder. But those answers are towards a local machine. How would I achieve something similar on AWS?

Apologies for the dumb question.